# What is a root shell?

Tags: command-line, root

can someone please help me, im so new at this whole thing. and ive been looking all day for an app that is a "root shell" What is a root shell?
Why can’t I find an all that has that?

Comment: Why do you need "root shell"? Where were you instructed to use it? Please [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1335668/edit) your question and add this information.

Comment: Please provide OS & release details.  Your question is *vague* and *unclear* especially on a Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu does not use the `root` user shell by default.  Instead, the `root` is disabled by default.  As such there is no 'root shell' shortcut application.

The way you run commands as superuser is by using `sudo` straight on the terminal directly, and provide your user's password to attempt to use `sudo` privileges.  There is no 'root shell' application in an Ubuntu system.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/196740/how-to-fix-an-ubuntu-system-when-it-wont-boot/ "Leaves the menu and goes to a root shell prompt". What is the difference between this and the 'normal' shell?